# How do I install Cython, cartopy and shapely in a python docker container?

Tags: python, docker, cython, cartopy

I am trying to get `Cython`, `cartopy` and `shapely` running in a docker container so I can leverage a python library `traffic`. I am currently getting an error with Cython:

```
Collecting Cython==0.26 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/6c/53a9e636c9dbe7acd5c002422c1a7a48a367f3b4c0cf6490908f43398ca6/Cython-0.26-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (7.0MB)
Collecting geos (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/9b/a190f02fb92f465a7640b9ee7da732d91610415a1102f6e9bb08125a3fef/geos-0.2.2.tar.gz (365kB)
Collecting cartopy (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/92/fe8838fa8158931906dfc4f16c5c1436b3dd2daf83592645b179581403ad/Cartopy-0.17.0.tar.gz (8.9MB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-Se89QB/cartopy/setup.py", line 42, in <module>
        raise ImportError('Cython 0.15.1+ is required to install cartopy.')
    ImportError: Cython 0.15.1+ is required to install cartopy.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Se89QB/cartopy/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Below is my setup:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
#apt-get install -y build-essential -y  python python-dev python-pip python-virtualenv libmysqlclient-dev curl&& \
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential -y  python python-dev python-pip python-virtualenv libmysqlclient-dev curl&& \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
# Install cron
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install cron
# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/simple-cron
# Add shell script and grant execution rights
ADD script.sh /script.sh
RUN chmod +x /script.sh
# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/simple-cron
# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Cython==0.26
geos
cartopy
shapely
traffic
```

Answer (score 2):

Since 2022-09-09 this is much easier, because Cartopy [v0.21.0](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/releases/tag/v0.21.0) does not depend on PROJ.

#### Solution

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye

RUN apt update && apt install -y git gcc build-essential python3-dev libgeos-dev

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

ADD requirements.txt .
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --compile -r requirements.txt

# add files and set cmd/entrpypoint down here
```

**requirements.txt:**

```
Cartopy==0.21.0
```

#### Test

```bash
docker build -t cartopy -f Dockerfile .
docker run -it cartopy pip freeze
```

Results in:

```
Cartopy==0.21.0
certifi==2022.12.7
contourpy==1.0.6
cycler==0.11.0
fonttools==4.38.0
kiwisolver==1.4.4
matplotlib==3.6.2
numpy==1.23.5
packaging==22.0
Pillow==9.3.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyproj==3.4.0
pyshp==2.3.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
Shapely==1.8.5.post1
six==1.16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Cython first with `pip`, before using your `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

cartopy has a lot of dependencies, and some -- especially Proj -- may not be resolvable using PIP or apt-get. numpy and cython may be resolved by installing them separately and just prior to installing cartopy (like u/dopplershift suggests) -- but Proj will never resolve, grr.

My solution was to use conda install, which solves the dependencies for you. Unfortunately Docker and Conda don't play well together, but you can kind of work around it using miniconda. Try this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
FROM python:3.8.5

RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

# cartopy cannot be installed using PIP because the proj never gets resolved.
# The proj dependency never gets resolved because there are two Python packages
# called proj, and PIP always loads the wrong one. The conda install command,
# however, using the conda-forge channel, does know how to resolve the dependency
# issues, including packages like numpy.
#
# Here we install miniconda, just so we can use the conda install command
# for cartopy.

FROM continuumio/miniconda3
RUN conda install -c conda-forge cartopy
```